# add data from an array in string and order it

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm triying to order a string depending on items length

this is the array

```
var quote = [
  0: {ref1: 'CE255X', price_u: '1024100'},
  1: {ref1: 'M-TK137', price_u: '65400'},
  2: {ref1: '126A‎‎‎', price_u: '242300'},
  3: {ref1: 'M-CE278A', price_u: '35000'},
  4: {ref1: 'M-Q2612A‎‎‎‎‎‎', price_u: '35000'},
  5: {ref1: 'M-Q7551X', price_u: '130002'},
  6: {ref1: '507A', price_u: '905300'},
  7: {ref1: 'M-35A/36A/85A/78A', price_u: '35000'},
]
```

this is the code that I tried

```
let i = 0;
let detail = '';
for (let index = 0; index < quote.length; index++) {
 i++;

 if (quote[index].ref1.length <= 50) {
   detail += i + '.' + quote[index].ref1.padEnd(38, '‎‎‎#');
   detail += quote[index].price_u  + '\n';
 }
}
console.log(detail);
```

If data show this

```
1.CE255X‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#1024100
2.M-TK137‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎65400
3.126A‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎242300
4.M-CE278A‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎35000
5.M-Q2612A‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎35000
6.M-Q7551X‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎130002
7.507A‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎905300
8.M-35A/36A/85A/78A‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎35000
```

I want to order it in this way, replacing the `#` for white spaces

```
1.CE255X‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#########1024100
2.M-TK137‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎########65400
3.126A‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎##########242300
4.M-CE278A‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎#######35000
5.M-Q2612A‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎#######35000
6.M-Q7551X‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎#######‎130002
7.507A‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎##########905300
8.M-35A/36A/85A/78A‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎‎‎#‎35000
```

Any help I will appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the length of the longest `ref1` property by using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the `ref1` length of each item, then [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get the maximum of the resulting array.

Add 4 to the result and set that as the target length when padding:

```js
var quote = [
  {ref1: 'CE255X', price_u: '1024100'},
  {ref1: 'M-TK137', price_u: '65400'},
  {ref1: '126A', price_u: '242300'},
  {ref1: 'M-CE278A', price_u: '35000'},
  {ref1: 'M-Q2612A', price_u: '35000'},
  {ref1: 'M-Q7551X', price_u: '130002'},
  {ref1: '507A', price_u: '905300'},
  {ref1: 'M-35A/36A/85A/78A', price_u: '35000'},
]

let i = 0;
let detail = '';

let maxLen = Math.max(...quote.map(e => e.ref1.length)) + 4

for (let index = 0; index < quote.length; index++) {
 i++;

 if (quote[index].ref1.length <= 50) {
   detail += i + '.' + quote[index].ref1.padEnd(maxLen, '#');
   detail += quote[index].price_u  + '\n';
 }
}
console.log(detail);
```

Comment: @Alexis no problem :)